# Client to send an email to server in java

Tags: java, email

In my project i want user to send an email to server while filling contact us form. And user may not put his email-id in the form (In jsp i have fields like name,message etc. ). And i want the message to be sent to the admin's gmail account. So is this possible that without putting **from username and password** , he can send mail on click of submit. I searched many answers but everywhere we have  put from username.I tried but i got      `"javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException"`

Comment: Please clarify, the mail would be sent by the server when the form is submitted?

Comment: @henry, My assumption is that mail should be sent by client(without specifying his email-id) to server mail-id when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your credentials. This is needed by specification of email servers.

You may use an extra email like user@company.com, and send provided data from this server to your admin smtp server like admin@company.com.